# Display information from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, output, line

I have a code that display on the page the information of a specific user, from a MySQL table. However, the informaiton is all displayed on a simple line, back to back. What I want, is to display the information of each line in diffrent blocks. So my question: how can I «brake» the line, to create many diffrent blocks of information, that I can put were I want on my page?

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo $row['Column A'] . " " . $row['Column B'] . " " . $row['Column C'] . " ";
} ?>
```

Comment: save this data into variable (instead of `echo`ing) and use them elsewhere

Comment: very very basic question about `<br>` or `\n`

Comment: Actually, you have to consider that ALL the info related to a specific user is displayed... not only one line of the table! But all the line with the ID X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should change your mysql_* functions to another functions like PDO & mysqli

About your question is how to generate HTML from your DB data there are multiple of ways

**One could be like this**

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
<h1><?php echo $row['columnA']; ?></h1>
<div class="myclass"><?php echo $row['columnb']; ?></div>
<img src="<?php echo $row['columnC']; ?>">
<?php
} ?>
```

**Two could be**

```
 <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $str = ""; 
    $str .= "<h1>".$row['columnA']."</h1>"; 
    $str .= '<div class="myclass">'.$row['columnb'].'</div>'; 
    $str .= '<img src="'.$row['columnC'].'">'; 
    echo $str; 
    <?php
    } ?>
```

**Or you can use a FW wich make it simpler for you**

**Or you can use a templating library which is the best way for you if you are not going to use a Framework**

check out mustache https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php

Of course you can change the HTML structure

I hope this can help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think a table might be what you are looking for...
(Don't forget to change to mysqli* as @Sedz mentioned in his answer)

```
<table border="1">
    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['Column A'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['Column B'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td></td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['Column C'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        };
    ?>
 </table>
```

Arrange the results in rows/cells as you see fit...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way is you pass the results into an array

```
$data = array(); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

And the break you are talking about

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo "$value<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple user2619310!

Add "\n" in your line.

Example:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      echo $row['Column A'] . " " . $row['Column B'] . " " . $row['Column C'] . "\n";

} 
?>
```

Bye! :-D

Answer (score 0):

How you break the lines can vary depending on what your objectives are and where you're going to use them. Here are some ways of having information on different lines:

1. Use the `br` tag at the end of each field.
2. Use DIVs to contain each row.
3. Use a table for each row.

DIVs will be the best if you're looking at different browsers and efficient sizing. But tables are also easy to implement for certain things.

Here's how I'd break the rows using tables.

```
<table>
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Column A label</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ColumnA']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column B label</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ColumnB']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column C label</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ColumnC']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

I don't have the slightest clue about your DB table structure but going by what you've shown, I have included an example. This is not tested but it should be good.

Also note the alternative PHP syntax for the while loop.